# Build Automation - Naming Best Practices

Tags: tfs, build, build-automation, naming, vnext

Relative to Build Definition Names, I have this setup of builds in Team Foundation Server

Family > Iteration (branch) > Application

I am trying to establish a uniform nomenclature for the build definitions, and since currently we have the concept on Folders in TFS vNext, I was looking for something like this:

Family Folder > Iteration Folder > Family.Iteration.Application

Where 
Family is something like Office365
Iteration is something like Alfa1, 2017.1, etc
Application is something like word

In this example would look like
Office365 > Alfa1 > Office365.Alfa1.Word

What do you guys think of this? What are the best practices in naming builds? How would you do it?

Thanks

Comment: According to my opinion, you want to make your build definition name = something like this `Office365.Alfa1.Word` .Did your single team project include multiple products? A build definition is team project level for now,why you have to make it so complicate? And for this kind of build definition name, how will it indicate the trigger? I could not know if it's a CI build / Gated build / Scheduled build?

Comment: Hello Patrick, at our company everything was a little custom made build system, and a mix with old xaml builds. I was trying to migrate everything to vNext build system in TFS 2017, and I'm having trouble finding guidlines about this. I'm kind of new to this, and i can know everything about how the build is made and how to do it, but i can't find guidlines about naming, and it's relation with CI and  triggers. Yes, there are different products in the Team Project, and different branches(it's not git). We use different branches with build at the same time.

Comment: I was first thinking about using the folder for the product family and phase separator, like Office365 > Alfa1 > Word, but the Release Manager has a strange bug when I relate the link artifact, i cannot see the folders in the relation, and duplications appear. So the conclusion was that build definition name to avoid duplications

Answer (score 0):

Your naming conventions seem kind of strange to me, though I doubt that is to any fault of your own. Your application should look more like a version number. I.E 2.30.1.13 - or "Major.Minor.Revision.Build". This makes sorting much easier. Major and minor kind of change at the discretion of management. Revision changes when there is a bug fix and the build just increments with every build you run. Your iteration folder I would keep as just "Major.Minor" and the next folder would be "Major.Minor.Revision.Build" although this kind of depends on naming conventions you currently use.

Comment: Hello Candace,
We are talking about different things
We usually don't use versioning in build naming, You use in your own builds?

I was thinking about what you said. Maybe you are talking about storage, deployment folder?

\\server\Family\Major.Minor\Major.Minor.Revision.Build?

I'm asking about build definition naming.